# expected speedup Numba/CUDA versus Numpy

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I'm new to Numba and CUDA and have done measurements to compare cuda jitted functions to Numpy on a few basic examples. For example,

```
@cuda.jit("void(float32[:])")
def gpu_computation(array):
    pos = cuda.grid(1)
    if pos < array.size:
        array[pos] = array[pos] ** 2.6
```

compared to single threaded

```
def cpu_computation(array):
    array = array ** 2.6
    return array
```

with

```
n=1000000
array = np.linspace(0, 100, num=n, dtype=np.float32)
threads per block = 32 
blocks per grid = 31250
```

I get about 3x speedup with the GPU. This is also what I get when performing matrix multiplication (both the basic and the smart versions found in the Numba documentation). Optimizing with copying to/from the device did not help.

Is this speedup expected? I expected an order of magnitude more. My machine: Mac OSX with GeForce GTX 775M 2048 MB and CUDA 7.5.30.

Answer (score 2):

Double precision arithmetic throughput of your GTX 775M is [1/24th of the single precision throughput](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-instructions).
As Python does not have a single precision type, you need to use [Numba types](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html) to explicitly mark your data as single precision.

Unfortunately there is no way to speed up double precision calculations other than using a different GPU (Tesla lineup or the original, now out-of-production GTX Titan).

Comment: Thanks, seems important to know. I updated the code snippet above to show what I am measuring now, but I don't see a difference so far.